# IValueConverter.ConvertBack not firing

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, ivalueconverter

I want to make my own DateTimePicker (WhenView) and have it two-way bind to a yyyyMMddHHmm string. I'm relatively new to XAML so may be missing something basic!

The WhenView is on the top, which displays Year,Month,Day,Hours, Minutes,Seconds one after another.

A TextBox is on the bottom, which is there just to display the underlying yyyyMMddHHmm string for debug.

[image]

**Control Model:** (When)

```
public class When : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };

    int _yea; public int Yea { get { return _yea; } set { _yea = value; PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Yea")); } }
    int _mon; public int Mon { get { return _mon; } set { _mon = value; PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Mon")); } }
    int _day; public int Day { get { return _day; } set { _day = value; PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Day")); } }
    int _hou; public int Hou { get { return _hou; } set { _hou = value; PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Hou")); } }
    int _min; public int Min { get { return _min; } set { _min = value; PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Min")); } }
    int _sec; public int Sec { get { return _sec; } set { _sec = value; PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Sec")); } }

    public When()
        : this(DateTime.Now)
    {
    }

    public When(DateTime dt)
    {
        Yea = dt.Year;
        Mon = dt.Month;
        Day = dt.Day;
        Hou = dt.Hour;
        Min = dt.Minute;
        Sec = dt.Second;
    }

    public DateTime ToDateTime()
    {
        return new DateTime(Yea, Mon, Day, Hou, Min, Sec);
    }
}
```

**Control View:** (WhenView)

```
<UserControl x:Class="DateBind.WhenView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
<StackPanel Margin="16">
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Yea, Mode=TwoWay}" />
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Mon, Mode=TwoWay}" />
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Day, Mode=TwoWay}" />
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Hou, Mode=TwoWay}" />
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Min, Mode=TwoWay}" />
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Sec, Mode=TwoWay}" />
</StackPanel>
```

**IValueConverter:** (WhenConverter) To facilitate binding to a string:

```
    [ValueConversion(typeof(string), typeof(When))]
public class WhenConverter : IValueConverter
{
    const string Format = @"yyyyMMddHHmm";

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is string)
        {
            DateTime parsedDate = DateTime.ParseExact(value as string, Format, null);
            return new When(parsedDate);
        }

        return null;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is When)
        {
            if (targetType == typeof(string))
            {
                return ((When)value).ToDateTime().ToString(Format);
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

---

So that's the building blocks done.

**MainWindow Code-behind** I'm storing the Date string in the MainWindow for brevity, it's in a data class in my real application.

```
    public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };

    string _date;
    public string Date 
    {
        get { return _date; } 
        set { _date = value; PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Date")); } 
    }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Date = "1234" + "01" + "02" + "0101";
        DataContext = this;
    }
}
```

**MainWindow XAML:**
*(I've added a simple TextBox for testing purposes.)*

```
<Window x:Class="DateBind.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
    xmlns:local ="clr-namespace:DateBind">
<StackPanel>
    <StackPanel.Resources>
        <local:WhenConverter x:Key="WhenConverter"></local:WhenConverter>
    </StackPanel.Resources>
    <local:WhenView DataContext="{Binding Date, Converter={StaticResource WhenConverter}, Mode=TwoWay}"></local:WhenView>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Date}"></TextBox>
</StackPanel>
```

What works:

- TextBox and WhenControl is initialised with the initial Date successfully
- Updating the value in the TextBox updates WhenControl successfully

The problem:

- Updating any value in the WhenControl does not update the TextBox (and therefore I expect, the underlying data value)
- PropertyChanged is getting fired within the When class, but I don't know what else to do to have it make the TextBox/underlying data update.

Comment: In your xaml code, what is the purpose of the line before the textbox ? You could merely use the converter in the binding of `Text` property of the `Textbox`. Since you have added the converter on the DataContext property which won't change, it's normal that `ConvertBack` won't be reached

Comment: The line before the TextBox "<local:WhenView..." instantiates the WhenView control.


The TextBox is just there for show, to prove whether the value has been edited by the WhenView control. Setting anything further on this shouldn't be of any help to me.


I have got ConvertBack working on the DataContext before, using a simple IValueConverter which reverses the string, on another TextBox. 


e.g. <TextBox Text="{Binding Date, Converter={StaticResource ReverseConverter}}"></TextBox>

Comment: Have you tried setting the binding in your TextBox to Mode=TwoWay?

Comment: 2 very good ways of diagnosing why a WPF binding is not behaving as you expect are; 1. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.presentationtracesources.tracelevel%28v=vs.110%29.aspx this involves setting up tracing and monitoring the output window in Visual Studio (make sure you have verbose logging turned on for bindings). 2. Download snoop and hook it up to your application as it will let you view what is in each control + their DataContexts.

Comment: @Bijington Mode=TwoWay did not seem to have an effect. Thank you for the debugging tools advice!